# Django: Annotate based on annotations with conditional

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm doing this at the end of an annotation chain on my queryset:

```
.annotate(diff=F("total_views")/F("previous_views")
```

The issue is that both `total_views` and `previous_views` are annotations themselves. This is working, except when `F("previous_views")` equals 0. I then get a division by zero error. All attempts to use `Case`/`When` have failed.

I'm looking for a way to calculate `diff` as a fraction, unless `previous_views` is `0`, in which case diff should be `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it's possible to use the annotation as if it was a regular field in the `When` clause:

```
.annotate(
                diff=Case(
                    When(previous_views__gt=0, then= F("total_views") - F("previous_views"))
                , default=None, output_field=FloatField())
            )
```